# MS-access 2007 case-based capacity planner for tender consultants,

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

As a way to score points for the study I’m doing, as well as out of interest into databases and wanting to help my team I’m trying to build a capacity planning tool in MS Access 2007. I work in a department that handles registering and supporting tenders. I have attached two pictures of what I’m trying to do here.

I’ve already spent some weeks making multiple iterations with colleagues who are involved and help write VBA and SQL (out of interest, wanting to learn something or otherwise. Our core business, however, isn’t developing).  The primary goal of the database is as follows:

1. A user can access, create and modify “cases” that correlates to a case ID that we use in a different system.
2. A user can write down his capacity per week per year for a case.
3. multiple users can assign themselves to a case.
4. Users can leave messages (records) for other users to see on a case
5. Metadata can be attached to the case

**The main problem we seem to be running into is that whenever a user tries through to edit an existing case through the overview, the case data no longer “complies” with entries elsewhere. Forcing updates through visual basic also seems to not have worked so far.**

Adding to the complexity: most of the names we use are in dutch.

Here is an overview of the relations.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYryC.jpg

Here is a screenshot of the case overview as seen by a user.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBSXH.jpg

**Main question:**
How can I make entire records change for multiple users based on the input of one user.

In compliance with the guidelines regarding asking subjective questions I’m trying to be a bit more precise here:

Additionally I’m uncertain:

1. whether it is our approach that is wrong,
2. if perhaps we’re overlooking a glaring issue, or
3. if we should redesign this from scratch with a  different layout.

Any help specifying where we should look or what would be advisable to do would be much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Timo

Comment: Can you post the images in the post, I cant access them.

Comment: Hey Nathan, A colleague tried to open the links I added in my post. He said they worked fine for them. Could you try these?
(db relations) http://i.imgur.com/O022LAG.png
(overview) http://i.imgur.com/kuENqaq.png

Comment: Web filters block them